# Search numbers in a multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do I count how much times a number is in the 2 dimensional table ?

Code example:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => int 19
      1 => int 17
      2 => int 37
      3 => int 3
      4 => int 17
      5 => int 11
      6 => int 23
  1 => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => int 16
      1 => int 30
      2 => int 16
      3 => int 4
      4 => int 24
      5 => int 14
      6 => int 15
  2 => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => int 11
      1 => int 41
      2 => int 30
      3 => int 11
      4 => int 10
      5 => int 18
      6 => int 36
```

i'm trying to find out how to search how many times each number is in the table.
This is what I got :

```
$arrayWeeknummer = array();

echo "<table>";
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    for($j = 0; $j < 7; $j++)
    {
        $arrayWeeknummer[$i][$j] = rand(1,42);
        echo "<td>".$arrayWeeknummer[$i][$j]."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

for($k = 0; $k < 42; $k++)
{
    $aantal = 0;
    $newArray[$k][0] = $k+1;

    if(array_search($k+1, $arrayWeeknummer))
    {
        $newArray[$k][1] = $aantal++;
    }

$newArray[$k][1] = $aantal;
}
```

Unfortunately i'm doing something wrong in my if (array_search) statement since it never get called.

Comment: can't you just use `array_count_values`?

Comment: so you want to find the occcurence of number in each week ?

Comment: the occurence of a number over all weeks

Comment: array_walk_recursive() should allow you to simplify walking through the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I just go through all elements with 2 foreach loop and then check if the value is already in my `$result` array, if not I initialize it with 0 and then increment it every time it is in the array.

```
<?php

    $result = [];

    foreach($arr as $a){
        foreach($a as $v){
            if(!isset($result[$v]))
                $result[$v] = 0;
            $result[$v]++;
        }
    }

    print_r($result);

?>
```

Or if you want to use [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) just do it like this:

```
$result = [];

array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v, $k)use(&$result){
    if(!isset($result[$v]))
        $result[$v] = 0;
    $result[$v]++;
});
```

Comment: @Awa You're welcome! (BTW: Added also the solution if you want to use `array_walk_recursive()`, maybe even a bit less code)

Comment: The big benefit of using array_walk_recursive() is that it can handle as many dimensions as the array holds, not simply 2

Comment: What If I want an array of 42 elements and not only the elements which are in table ?

Comment: @Awa Then initialize `$result` with this: `$result = array_combine(range(1,42), array_fill(0, 42, 0));`

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to make an array with keys from 1 to 42 and with values initialized at 0. Then simply run a `for` loop into another `for` loop to look up every value in your array, and simply increment the value corresponding to the value in your array going from 1 to 42.

Edit : seems like `array_count_values()` does the same

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

    $input = [
    [
            0 =>  19,
            1 =>  17,
            2 =>  37,
            3 =>  3,
            4 =>  17,
            5 =>  11,
            6 =>  23],
            [
            0 =>  45,
            1 =>  1,
            2 =>  17,
            3 =>  34,
            4 =>  18,
            5 =>  19,
            6 =>  26],
    ];

    $max = 0;

    foreach($input as $array) {
        $max = max(max($array), $max);
    }

    $result = array_fill (0, $max, 0);

    foreach($input as $array) {
        foreach($array as $number) {
            $result[$number]++;
        }
    } 

print_r($result);
```

Comment: OP's array is multidimensional

Comment: Edited as multidimentional